# Connection pool keeps closing in Neptune

Tags: aws-lambda, gremlin-server, amazon-neptune

I am having a problem to execute gremlin queries on a lambda function that intends to ingest into Amazon Neptune.

Time and time again I receive these logs:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDH3S.png)

I followed the specifications that Amazon itself has in this page https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/lambda-functions-examples.html

all the code is the same.

Comment: Does your Lambda function have access to the Neptune VPC? If you put a simple HTTP request to the /status Neptune API does it succeed?

Comment: They're in the same VPC and security group so that shouldn't be a problem...

Comment: It's still good as a test to see if you can reach the /status endpoint.  That will rule out any network or IAM permission type issues.